# How to convert string to an operable array?

Tags: c++

I have a CSV file with the following data for example

```
   X1 X2 X3
Y1 aa dd 15
Y2 bb ee 20
Y3 cc ff 25
```

How can I for the second column calculate the sum and write the percentage of that sum near each value (add a new column in the CSV file)? For example:

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4
Y1 aa dd 15 25%
Y2 bb ee 20 33%
Y3 cc ff 25 42%
```

I have already put all values in the fourth column into a vector.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream> 
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream infile("aaa.csv");
    vector<float> investment;

    int i = 0;
        while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        i++;
        if (i == 1) {
            continue;
        }
        istringstream sin(line); 
        vector<string> fields; 
        string field;
        while (getline(sin, field, ',')) 
        {
            fields.push_back(field); 
        }

        double p;
        string temp = fields[3];


    }
}
```

Now I am confused about how to convert the string to a float-type array so that I can do some calculation.

Comment: std::stof perhaps?

Comment: Concerning _add a new column in the CSV file_: Either read file into memory (and close input stream), then overwrite file with new contents (i.e. added column), or read old file and write new file with different name (concurrently) row by row in one loop.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to read some sort of csv data. I assume that your shown data is just an example and not the real file. Because later on, you are searching for a comma.

The reading of such CSV files is a standard task and I will give you detailed explanations. In the end all the reading of the file will be done in a one-liner. If the file would look different then this would be also OK.

Then you want to do some mathematical operation and stream out the result.

To implement this task I will use "modern" C++ elements.

In modern C++ you have algorithms that iterate over ranges. You will often see something like "someAlgoritm(container.begin(), container.end(), someLambda)". The idea is that we iterate over some similar elements.

In your case we iterate over tokens in your input string, and create substrings. This is called tokenizing.

And for exactly that purpose, we have the `std::sregex_token_iterator`. And because we have something that has been defined for such purpose, we should use it.

This thing is an iterator. For iterating over a string, hence sregex. The begin part defines, on what range of input we shall operate, then there is a `std::regex` for what should be matched / or what should not be matched in the input string. The type of matching strategy is given with last parameter.

- 1 --> give me the stuff that I defined in the regex and
- -1 --> give me that what is NOT matched based on the regex.

So, now that we understand the iterator, we can std::copy the tokens from the iterator to our target, a `std::vector` of `std::string`. And since we do not know, how may columns we have, we will use the `std::back_inserter` as a target. This will add all tokens that we get from the `std::sregex_token_iterator` and append it ot our `std::vector<std::string>>`. It does'nt matter how many columns we have.

Good. Such a statement could look like

```
std::copy(                          // We want to copy something
    std::sregex_token_iterator      // The iterator begin, the sregex_token_iterator. Give back first token
    (
        line.begin(),               // Evaluate the input string from the beginning
        line.end(),                 // to the end
        re,                         // Add match a comma
        -1                          // But give me back not the comma but everything else 
    ),
    std::sregex_token_iterator(),   // iterator end for sregex_token_iterator, last token + 1
    std::back_inserter(cp.columns)  // Append everything to the target container
);
```

Now we can understand, how this copy operation works.

Please note, The numbers will be converted from a string to a float in th below example. Therefore we will not use `std::copy` but `std::transform`. Bu of course the mechanism is the same.

Next step. We want to read from a file. The file contains also some kind of same data. The same data are rows.

And as for above, we can iterate of similar data. If it is the file input or whatever. For this purpose C++ has the `std::istream_iterator`. This is a template and as a template parameter it gets the type of data that it should read and, as a constructor parameter it gets a reference to an input stream. It doesnt't matter, if the input stream is a `std::cin`, or a `std::ifstream` or a `std::istringstream`. The behaviour is identical for all kinds of streams.

And since we do not have files an SO, I use (in the below example) a `std::istringstream` to store the input csv file. But of course you can open a file, by defining a `std::ifstream testCsv(filename)`. No problem.

And with `std::istream_iterator`, we iterate over the input and read similar data. In our case one problem is that we want to iterate over special data and not over some build in data type.

To solve this, we define a Proxy class, which does the internal work for us (we do not want to know how, that should be encapsulated in the proxy). In the proxy we overwrite the type cast operator, to get the result to our expected type for the `std::istream_iterator`.

And the last important step. A `std::vector` has a range constructor. It has also a lot of other constructors that we can use in the definition of a variable of type `std::vector`. But for our purposes this constructor fits best.

So we define a variable csv and use its range constructor and give it a begin of a range and an end of a range. And, in our specific example, we use the begin and end iterator of `std::istream_iterator`.

If we combine all the above, reading the complete CSV file is a *one-liner*, it is the definition of a variable with calling its range constructor.

The mathematical operation is ultra simple. We will calculate the sum and add the resulting percentage as a new column. For that we will use 2 `std::for_each` statements.

Please see the resulting code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>

std::istringstream testCsv{ R"(00,01,15
10,11,20
20,21,25)" };

// Define Alias for easier Reading
using Columns = std::vector<float>;
using CSV = std::vector<Columns>;
// The delimiter
const std::regex re(",");

// Proxy for the input Iterator
struct ColumnProxy {    
    // Overload extractor. Read a complete line
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ColumnProxy& cp) {

        // Read a line
        std::string line; cp.columns.clear();
        std::getline(is, line);
        if (!line.empty()) {

            // Split values and copy into resulting vector
            std::transform(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1),
                std::sregex_token_iterator(),
                std::back_inserter(cp.columns),
                [](const std::string& s){ return std::stof(s);});
        }
        return is;
    }

    // Type cast operator overload.  Cast the type 'Columns' to std::vector<std::string>
    operator Columns() const { return columns; }
protected:
    // Temporary to hold the read vector
    Columns columns{};
};


int main()
{
    // Define variable CSV with its range constructor. Read complete CSV in this statement, So, one liner
    CSV csv{ std::istream_iterator<ColumnProxy>(testCsv), std::istream_iterator<ColumnProxy>() };

    // Calculate the sum of the 2nd column    
    float sum{0.0};
    std::for_each(csv.begin(),csv.end(),[&sum](const Columns& c){sum += c.at(2);});
    // Calculate the percentage of the element from the overall sum
    std::for_each(csv.begin(),csv.end(),[&sum](Columns& c){c.push_back(c.at(2)/sum);});

    // Debug Output.  Print matrix to std::cout
    std::for_each(csv.begin(), csv.end(), [](const Columns &c) {
        std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; });

    return 0;
}
```

The result is a ultra simple piece of code with a high flexibility.

In function main, you will see just some statements.

I hope it helps . . .